# Android: two activities, one tab

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

What I want to do is the following:

I have 4 tabs in total, but in 1 tab i want to have multiple screens which the user can change using the menu
I can capture the event of when the user presses the right button, so no help needed there:)
what I can't do is starting the Activity without removing the TabBar!
I found some information about changing the view of the framelayout, but i really want to start another activity in the layout, not just change the view (I want to keep my code clean you see;)

thanks in advance
so in Tab A I want to be able to use Activity A and B

Comment: have u solved this. kindly share the code. i want this also. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I found is still replacing the view, but doing it through ActivityGroup, so the code would still look normally and would be separated in activities. Works great, but there still is needs for hacks like back button press and stuff.

Scrapped this idea, though, since later I wanted more flexible and more stylish tab bar, so I wrote my own. Works like a charm and took some 2 working days to code.